# Dataframe from sibling XML items

Tags: xml, r

I have few XML items `Series` structured as

```
<Series>
  <SeriesKey>
  <Value concept="LOCATION" value="NOR"/>
  <Value concept="TRANSACT" value="B1_GA"/>
  <Value concept="MEASURE" value="CXC"/>
  </SeriesKey>
  <Attributes>
  <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P1Y"/>
  <Value concept="UNIT" value="USD"/>
  <Value concept="POWERCODE" value="6"/>
  </Attributes>
  <Obs>
  <Time>1970</Time>
  <ObsValue value="12729.77490809"/>
  </Obs>
  <Obs>
  <Time>1971</Time>
  <ObsValue value="14505.3225330031"/>
  </Obs>
  <Obs>
  <Time>1972</Time>
  <ObsValue value="17219.5954919744"/>
  </Obs>
  </Series>
<Series>
  <SeriesKey>
   <Value concept="LOCATION" value="USA"/>
   <Value concept="TRANSACT" value="B1_GA"/>
   <Value concept="MEASURE" value="CXC"/>
  </SeriesKey>
  <Attributes>
   <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P1Y"/>
   <Value concept="UNIT" value="USD"/>
   <Value concept="POWERCODE" value="6"/>
   </Attributes>
    ...
  </Series>
```

I want to combine all `Series` to build a dataframe structured as

```
data.frame(LOCATION=rep("NOR",3),
           TRANSACT=rep("B1_GA",3),
           TIME=c(1970,1971,1972),
           VALUE=c(12729.77490809, 14505.3225330031, 17219.5954919744))
# LOCATION TRANSACT TIME    VALUE
# 1      NOR    B1_GA 1970 12729.77
# 2      NOR    B1_GA 1971 14505.32
# 3      NOR    B1_GA 1972 17219.60
```

From the original document stored here

```
url <- "http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/SNA_TABLE1/NOR+CAN+FRA+DEU+GBR+USA+ITA+JAP.B1_GA+B1G_P119+B1G+B1GVA+B1GVB_E+B1GVC+B1GVF+B1GVG_I+B1GVJ+B1GVK+B1GVL+B1GVM_N+B1GVO_Q+B1GVR_U+D21_D31+D21S1+D31S1+DB1_GA.CXC/all?startTime=1950&endTime=2013"
```

I can access single items with

```
xml <- xmlParse(url)

ns<-xmlNamespaceDefinitions(xml, simplify=T)
names(ns)[1] <- "def"   #assign name "def"
```

and

```
length(xpathSApply(xml, "//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series/def:SeriesKey/def:Value[@concept='LOCATION']/@value", namespaces=ns))
# [1] 123

length(xpathSApply(xml, "//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series/def:Obs", namespaces=ns))
# [1] 3959
```

but I can't see any easy way to assign each `Obs` to its `SeriesKey`.

Comment: You show no namespaces in your sample xml but it looks like from your code that there actually are.  Can you update to show a better representation of the xml

Comment: @RichardScriven The whole document is [here](http://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/SNA_TABLE1/NOR+CAN+FRA+DEU+GBR+USA+ITA+JAP.B1_GA+B1G_P119+B1G+B1GVA+B1GVB_E+B1GVC+B1GVF+B1GVG_I+B1GVJ+B1GVK+B1GVL+B1GVM_N+B1GVO_Q+B1GVR_U+D21_D31+D21S1+D31S1+DB1_GA.CXC/all?startTime=1950&endTime=2013)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think you can get away from using the namespaces if you operate on the root document, i.e. `xmlRoot`

Answer (score 1):

Far from elegant but still...

```
df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(xpathSApply(xml, "//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series", namespaces=ns))) {
  location <- xpathSApply(xml, paste0("//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series[",i,"]/def:SeriesKey/def:Value[@concept='LOCATION']/@value"), namespaces=ns)
  transact <- xpathSApply(xml, paste0("//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series[",i,"]/def:SeriesKey/def:Value[@concept='TRANSACT']/@value"), namespaces=ns)
  measure <- xpathSApply(xml, paste0("//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series[",i,"]/def:SeriesKey/def:Value[@concept='MEASURE']/@value"), namespaces=ns)

  time <- xpathSApply(xml, paste0("//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series[",i,"]/def:Obs/def:Time"), xmlValue, 
                      namespaces=ns)
  value <- xpathSApply(xml, paste0("//message:MessageGroup/def:DataSet/def:Series[",i,"]/def:Obs/def:ObsValue/@value"), 
                       namespaces=ns)

  tmp <- data.frame(location=rep(location, length(time)),
                    transact=rep(transact, length(time)),
                    measure=rep(measure, length(time)),
                    time=time,
                    value=value)

  df <- rbind(df, tmp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really much better, but... grab the data and namespaces

```
xml <- xmlParse(url)
ns <- xmlNamespaceDefinitions(xml, simplify=TRUE)
names(ns)[1] = "def"
```

Create an R list of Series nodes, using "//" on the assumption that the XML has consistent structure so full path specification is not required.

```
series <- getNodeSet(xml, "//def:Series", namespaces=ns)
```

For the single-element components, iterate over each node and use the xpathSApply function to extract the value; the query ".//" means relative to the current Series.

```
q <- ".//def:SeriesKey/def:Value[@concept='LOCATION']/@value"
LOCATION <- sapply(series, xpathSApply, q, namespaces=ns)
```

Maybe a less cryptic rendition of the above is

```
LOCATION <- sapply(series, function(elt) xpathSApply(elt, q, namespaces=ns))
```

For the nested components, do similar

```
q <- ".//def:Obs/def:Time"
TIME <- lapply(series, xpathSApply, q, xmlValue, namespaces=ns)

q <- ".//def:Obs/def:ObsValue/@value"
VALUE <- lapply(series, xpathSApply, q, namespaces=ns)
```

Figure out the geometry of the nesting, and use that to replicate the single elements as you construct the data frame; avoid using names both for efficiency and to avoid 'conveniences' in the data.frame() function.

```
geom <- sapply(TIME, length)
df <- data.frame(LOCATION=rep(unname(LOCATION), geom),
                 TIME=unlist(TIME, use.names=FALSE),
                 VALUE=unlist(VALUE, use.names=FALSE))
```

More or less at all costs you want to avoid rbind()ing data frames together as in @CptNemo's example -- this results in excessive copying and abysmal performance.

A more vectorized approach, placing further faith in the overall geometry of the file, is to extract elements from the XML rather than the node set (once the geometry is determined)

```
series <- getNodeSet(xml, "//def:Series", namespaces=ns)
geom <- sapply(series, xpathSApply, "count(.//def:Obs)", namespaces=ns)

LOCATION <- xpathSApply(xml, "//def:Value[@concept='LOCATION']/@value",
                        namespaces=ns)
TIME <- xpathSApply(xml, "//def:Time/text()", xmlValue, namespaces=ns)
```

etc.